# How do I add a SEO friendly URL structure to the Melt Framework?

Tags: php, melt-framework

The standard URL structure of [Melt](http://meltframework.org) uses underscores (_) for URLs.

I would however like to use a more SEO friendly URL structure with dashes (-) for URLs so that I get the structure **/foo-bar/** instead of **/foo_bar/**.

I imagine that I need to rewrite the request somehow but I do not exactly see how.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been added to [solutons](https://github.com/melt/melt/wiki/Solutions).

See "URL rewriting and fancy URL SEO optimization".